# Power BI Paginated Report - monthly parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, powerbi-paginated-reports

I require your guidance for my needs.

I want to create a parameter based on month that will help me filter the data report based on the selected month parameter. Example if the parameter I choose is January then I want to put the filter on my datasets only the January.

Currently I create default parameter by get the first date and last date of the current month and previous month. I want to upgrade these parameter with just select the month.

Hope you all can get what I need.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1- Create the parameter and enter the available values as a list manually

2- If you have a date table in your dataset, you can create a dataset that queries this table and returns the list of the months. You would then use this query as a source for your parameter

Comment: In the option 2, I'm using Power BI Dataset as my source data, is it still possible to use dataset table for the source of my parameter?

Comment: You need to create a seperate dataset for the parameter (from the same data source), The parameter dataset will refresh when you open your report, then the main dataset will refresh when the user selects values for all the parameters